# Conditionally Show Content or not inside deftemplate macro (Clojure - Enlive)

Tags: if-statement, clojure, macros, enlive

So far I've managed to figure out how to duplicate a div with clone-for, but I haven't found a function for conditionally applying a transformation, while inside the deftemplate macro.

```
(deftemplate threads "thread.html" [xs]
  [:div.entry] ;hook to a div
  (clone-for [x xs] ;for each in the array passed in
      (if (contains? x :picture) ;if picture in object
        ([:div.entry :> :img] (set-attr :src (:picture x))) ;show picture
        ([:div.entry] (set-attr :style "display:none;"))) ;else hide element
      ;do more things here
      ))

(threads [{:picture 'link goes here'},{},...])
```

returns

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key must be integer
```

I'm wondering if anyone more experienced with enlive could help? I'm not sure what the following should propely be written as.

```
  (if (contains? x :picture) ;if picture in object
        ([:div.entry :> :img] (set-attr :src (:picture x))) ;show picture
        ([:div.entry] (set-attr :style "display:none;"))) ;else hide element
```

EDIT: I've commented and cut out code not related to my question below, at the suggestion of Alan.

Comment: Can you add sample input & desired output? Also remove unneeded items like `time`, `uid`, etc.

Comment: I've cleaned it up a bit.